# Exceeds Gas Limit even though chain fully synced

Tags: gas-limit

I'm attempting to send a transactions via Ethereum Wallet, the latest version, and have run geth --syncmode="light" .  On the last 200k blocks or so I just opened Ethereum Wallet and let it sync the rest.  When I go to send a transaction, it says "exceeds gas limit" even though I have the gas limit max.  How can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending the transaction to a contract?

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons for you to get this error. But the most likely reason is  The contract to whom you are sending is having `assert` or `require` which is failing.